# Error when I populate lookup with external id using .put method

Tags: apex, sobject, describesobject, dynamic-dml

You can populate lookup fields using an object with an external id field populated like so:

```
Custom_Object__c o = new Custom_Object__c(Account__r=new Account(External_ID__c='123'));
insert o;
```

However, when I want to dynamically assign values using the `.put` method instead of the property, I receive an error:

```
Custom_Object__c co = new Custom_Object__c();
SObject new_obj = co.newSObject();
new_obj.put('Account__r', new Account(External_ID__c='123'));
```

From the above code I receive `Invalid field Account__r for Custom_Object__c`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are so close, this is not because you are using an External Id, it is because you are not using the right SObject method.

I have been caught out by this many times as well.

The correct syntax is:

```
new_obj.putSObject('Account__r', new Account(External_ID__c='123'));
```

Comment: I've used this method before; I don't know why I didn't check the method signatures on the sobject when I was looking through the documentation last night.  Thanks!

Comment: Can we use the same concept with Owner if I have a external Id on the user?